# Local error while trying to start browerstacklocal through nodejs

Tags: node.js, browserstack

"Local error could not connect to function due to network issues if you are behind the proxy please enable proxy" while trying to start browerstacklocal through nodejs

Not behind proxy.. when implemented in java, binary file is getting executed successfully

Answer (score 0):

You can review the sample project in the link:https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-local-nodejs and execute the test node-example.js for a working example of BrowserStack Local with Node JS